# Medalhas sobre visitas consecutivas não são contabilizadas

Tags: suporte, bug

Hoje percebi algo estranho referente as medalhas `Fanático` e `Entusiasta`, elas são referentes as visitas consecutivas no StackOverflow, porém não estão sendo contabilizadas. Eu não tenho tanta frequência em perguntar/responder mas visito diariamente algumas horas por dia e a contagem está congelada.

Há algum detalhe sobre a contabilização das visitas que eu não tenha entendido?

```
Fanático - Ouro - 9/100
Visitou o site 100 por dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)

Entusiasta - Prata - 9/30
Visitou o site 30 por dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)
```

Comment: Eu acho que isso já foi respondido antes, mas não encontro a pergunta.

Comment: Acho que há um problema com as visitas via app mobile, se não tiver atividade no site não conta como visita.

Comment: Não faço visitas via mobile. Mas que forma de atividade, @JorgeB ? Apesar de não responder/perguntar com tanta frequência, eu visualizo e voto as questões/soluções.

Comment: Marcelo deixa ver se aparece algum moderador para te responder.

Comment: Você também visita durante fins de semana? Tem alguma coisa que você faz no site durante a semana que deixa de fazer nos fins de semana? Seu calendário de visitas é constante de segunda à sexta, mas não nos fins de semana.

Comment: Só reduzo a frequência com que abro o stack, mas sempre estou acessando.

Comment: Me parece que não basta visitar, deve fazer alguma coisa.